# Autocomplete only works for onload components

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm using jquery autocomplete plugin for auto suggestions.

It loads only for the onload elements of the page.

How can I make it work for the elements loaded with jQuery through ajax?

Comment: How do you bind the autocomplete to the onload elements of the page? Won't binding it to the ajax loaded elements in the same way not possible?

Comment: I'm using autocomplete in Yii framework, It has built in support for jquery auto complete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `$(...).autocomplete(...)` (again) after appending the elements e.g. in the success callback of the ajax.

E.g.:

```
$(...).ajax({
    ...
    success: function(respond) {
        $(...).append(respond); // add new elements
        $(...).autocomplete(...); // add autocomplete to them
    }
    ...
});
```

P.s.: If you have an autocomplete element onload and only want to change their options, you can use the `source` parameter of automplete to get the values dynamically (without setting autocomplete again).